# Ionic 1: Erro ao compilar para iOS - [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1)

Tags: ios, ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Estou compilando pela primeira vez no Mac, para o iPhone, quando digito o comando para compilação:

```
cordova build ios
```

Surge o erro:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado....

Segue meu config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.vovocooks.vovocooksv7862011" version="1.6.2" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/7.0">
<name>VovóCooks</name>
<description>
Comidas deliciosas ou especiarias que não se encontram em restaurantes, 
começam com o VoVóCooks App.
    </description>
    <author email="contato@vovocooks.com.br" 
href="http://vovocooks.com.br/">
        Vovó Cooks
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="http://google.com" />
    <access origin="https://google.com" />
    <access origin="http://maps.google.com" />
    <access origin="http://*.google.com" />
    <access origin="content:///*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="8000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0000" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library:23+" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="23+" />
    <preference name="UseLegacySwiftLanguageVersion" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.15:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.23:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.7:8101" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://189.37.196.163:8100" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.6.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="fr._46cl.focus" spec="git+https://github.com/46cl/cordova-android-focus-plugin.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.6.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.1.8" />
    <plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="^4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="Geolocation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="^2.3.3" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="MEUID" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

Seguem os dados completos da compilação:

```
Mini-de-Andre:vovocooks-v10 andregnvlima$ ionic cordova build ios
The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.14.0 => 3.15.0)!

[WARN] No write permissions for global node_modules--automatic CLI updates are disabled.

       To fix, see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

       Or, install the CLI update manually:

       npm i -g ionic@latest


[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.
> cordova build ios
Discovered plugin "Geolocation" in config.xml. Adding it to the project

Failed to restore plugin "Geolocation" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/Geolocation


1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/andregnvlima/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VovóCooks-bzqaqcezjlluijhhnpogbliimghx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VovóCooks.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VovóCooks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o VovóCooks/Classes/AppDelegate.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC /Users/andregnvlima/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VovóCooks-bzqaqcezjlluijhhnpogbliimghx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/VovóCooks.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VovóCooks.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainViewController.o VovóCooks/Classes/MainViewController.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,VovóCooks.xcworkspace,-scheme,VovóCooks,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).
```

Quando vou instalar o plugin do Geolocation dá a mensagem:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.1.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on android.
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/andregnvlima/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geolocation': CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at /Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:367:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

Comment: Só obteve essa saída de erros ?

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Tentei colocar toda a mensagem de compilação, mas o stackoverflow não permitiu que ficou a cima do permitido.... mas segue editado a pergunta com os erros.

Comment: agora ele esta dizendo que o plugin depende de `cordova-plugin-compat`, informa ele no config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possivelmente esse plugin teve sua *URL* alterada, pode ser que a mesma estava em:

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/geolocation
```

Então em seu `config.xml` altere a alinha:

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" />
```

Para:

```
<plugin name="geolocation" />
```

> Obs: Talvez esse plugin não seja necessário, tente remover a linha e compilar, pois já se encontra no projeto o plugin *cordova-plugin-geolocation*
>
> - [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

Um algo a se observar, é que tem uma versão mais recente do *Ionic*, caso deseje atualizar, execute o comando:

```
npm i -g ionic@latest
```

Comment: Quando vou instalar o plugin geolocation no mac dá a mensagem:

Comment: Bem, não deu pra colar aqui, mas coloquei a mensagem da instalação do plugin no mac no final da pergunta.... e tem o JDK instalado lá...

Comment: Esse plugin `Geolocation` é muito antigo, faz anos que não recebe atualizações, tente remover a linha. Porque ja tem outro

Comment: Obrigado @Wéllingthon M. de Souza. Com sua dica fui descobrindo que precisava do cocoa e foi evoluindo. Agora o único erro é este aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249684/compilar-ionic-no-mac-ao-adicionar-plugin-diz-requirements-check-failed-for-j resolvi abrir em outro tópico para melhorar.