# Compilar Ionic no MAC: Ao adicionar plugin diz " Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater" mas já instalado

Tags: ios, ionic, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin

Quando vou adicionar a plataforma ios no Mac, dá a mensagem que o plugin codova file tranfer não foi instalado, para tentar com --force.

Mas ao instalar com o comando:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer --force
```

Dá o erro a seguir, não sei o que pode ser:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer --force
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-file-transfer from android
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-file-transfer from ios
Removing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
Removing plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer from config.xml file...
Removing cordova-plugin-file-transfer from package.json
Mini-de-Andre:vovocooks-v10 andregnvlima$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --force
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@2.1.0" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/andregnvlima/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file-transfer': CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
    at /Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:367:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/andregnvlima/app/vovocooks-v10/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

Comment: O que pode estar acontecendo, é que você tenha mais de uma versão instalada e a que está por padrão não é a *1.8* ... Execute o comando `javac -version` para saber qual versão está por padrão. Veja a [documentação](https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/help/version_manual.xml) do *Java*

Comment: está resultando javac 9.0.1

Comment: Veja seja o caso de reinstalar [10 JDK 8 Instalação para for OS X](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html)

Comment: Deu certo. Tinha que baixar o Java da Apple Aplicativos, o da Oracle dava esse erro.

Comment: Coloque como resposta, passo a passo se possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso instalar a versão do Java da Apple Store, não pode ser direta do site da Oracle e instalar o Cocoa.